# How to edit value retried from Regular expression extractor to pass it to next URL

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have one request on which I have used regular expression extractor. which returns me following value in group1 :

```
filetodownload_g1=C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\9_19_04_2016_09_40_44_279.zip
```

Now, I want to edit this to replace `\\` with `\.`

I tried with:

```
${__javaScript(${filetodownload_g1}.replace("\\","\"))}
```

But it is not working. It is returning nothing(blank).

Can we store this in user defined variable and edit? If not, which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Still its not working.

Comment: So, did you try `${__javaScript(${filetodownload_g1}.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\"))}`?

Comment: tried the same but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you need to do such a replacement, however here you go:

```
${__javaScript("${filetodownload_g1}".replace(/\\\/g\,"\\\."),)}
```

[image: JavaScript Replace]

See [JavaScript String replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) reference.

Also keep in mind that in JMeter Functions you need to escape any comma with a backslash as commas are reserved to separate function parameters. Unescaped comma -> wrong number or incorrect order of arguments -> malfunction.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guide for more information on JMeter Functions

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T.. that worked perfectly, it replaced \\ with \.  But I am facing further issues : it returns me below URL [link] 

http://Application.server.com/Stop/DownloadFile?fileLocation=C:\data folder\app\Client\Time\9_19_04_2016_09_40_44_279.zip     if I hit above URL in browser, it works fine but Jmeter is throwing me Illegal character in query exception... could someone spot what should I do to resolve this ?

Comment: Got the solution. I just had to tick "Encode ?" option in HTTP request section.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript replace expression should be `${__javaScript('${filetodownload_g1}'.replace(/\\\\/g\,'\\\\'))}`

As you need to do replace \\ with \, It should be very easy as \ is the escape char in javascript.

```
${__javaScript("${filetodownload_g1}")}  //this will return the string with single \
```